# An interesting geometry problem with angle bisectors and tangent

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, tangent-line

I have found the following problem: There is an acute $\triangle ABC$. Denote its circumcircle as $\omega$. The angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ intersects $BC$ and $\omega$ in points respectively $A_1$ and $M$, angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ intersects $AC$ and $\omega$ in respectively $B_1$ and $N$. Let $t$ be the tangent to $\omega$ in point $C$. Prove that $t$, $MN$ and $A_1B_1$ intersect in one point.

Here is the problem drawn with GeoGebra:
[image]

What I have found out:
It is obvious that $M$ is the middle point of the arc $BC$ and $N$ is the middle of $AC$. I know that I can solve the problem if I choose two of the given lines to intersect and prove that the third goes through their intersection point, but I have tried all pairs, but I can't find a way to prove it. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: By using OC=OA=OB=OM=ON,compute vector CA, vector CB,vectorBB1 vector AA1 vector AM vectorBN and vector OC・vectorCt.

Comment: How to I compute vector Ct? As perpendicular to vector OC?

Comment: No,compute all vector and at last prove OC・Ct=0

Comment: Oh, I see. I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: @TakahiroWaki maybe I'm stupid but I can't get vector Ct. How to find it? I'm not very familiar with vectors in geometry problems, I know only the basics(cross/dot product, addition, subtraction).

Comment: Although it is needed vector Ot,computation of this problem is hard.Also I gave up computation.But I think that these aims are correct.